# Pygame sprites - inactive after creating a new sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

I've got a problem with my sprites.

I created a sprite class:

```
class lumbercheck(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("holzfaeller.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def PlaceOnMap(self, pos):
        self.rect.center = pos
```

Added the sprite to groups:

```
lumbercheck_g = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain(lumbercheck)
allbuildings = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((lumbercheck, ...))
```

Now I start the game loop and ask for sprites collision:

```
if any(sprite.rect.collidepoint(pos) for sprite in allbuildings.sprites())
```

Then I place the Sprite on the map, where I clicked:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and holzfaeller is True and tilemap_1[pos_y][pos_x] == 3:
    lumbercheck.PlaceOnMap(pos)
    lumbercheck_g.draw(gameDisplay)
```

But I've got the problem that onyl the first sprite placed on the map is detected by the sprite collision. When I place a second one, only the second one works with the collision detection. The first one is still on the map but it seems like, it's not a sprite anymore.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess somewhere you override your class `lumbercheck` with an instance of that class, because `lumbercheck.PlaceOnMap(pos)` should not work if `lumbercheck` is still a class and `PlaceOnMap` is an instace method.